# RxJS6 Update Problems (mergeMap)

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have some problems after upgrading RxJS from version 5 to 6.

The previous code was:

```
    private updateSettingWithWebhookCreation(setting: Setting) {
        return this.webhookService.createWebhook(setting)
            .flatMap(webhookId => {
                setting.webhookId = webhookId;
                return this.updatePureSetting(setting) //returns Observable<Setting>
            })
            .flatMap((setting: Setting) => {
                return this.webhookService.updateWebhook(setting); //returns Observable<WebHook>
            });
    }
```

Now in v6 it should be:

```
  private updateSettingWithWebhookCreation(setting: Setting): Observable<Setting> {
    return this.webhookService.createWebhook(setting).pipe(
      mergeMap(webhookId => {
        setting.webhookId = webhookId;
        return this.updatePureSetting(setting)
      }),
      mergeMap((setting: Setting) => {
        return this.webhookService.updateWebhook(setting); //I just need the setting from the previous observable here
      }));
  }
```

But I get the following error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<Setting, Observable<Webhook>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Observable<Setting>, Observable<Webhook>>'.
```

Comment: Try to define type to `webhookId` like this `mergeMap( (webhookId: any) => {`

Comment: Thats not the problem. The error is in the second mergeMap.

Comment: I think you are missing `.` before `mergeMap` here `}),mergeMap((`, You have used comma `,`

Comment: No @hrdkisback , this is the new syntax in RxJS6 - You have to pipe everything. Anyway the problem here is now syntax error as my IDE would anyway tell me... The error i am having trouble with is on the bottom of my question.

Comment: I think the issue is that ```mergeMap``` returns an *Observable of Observables* while ```flatMap``` returns just one Observable. So, the issue seems to be that the first call to ```mergeMap``` implies that you return an Observable and it's not being flattered. Instead, an Observable of Obseravbles is returned. Then, the second call to ```mergeMap``` receives an item of the previous Observable, which is another Observable. Why don't you use ```flatMap``` instead?

Comment: Flatmap is the same to mergeMap. But indeed, looks like `this.webhookService.updateWebhook(setting);` returns Observable<Observable<Webhook>>

Comment: Just to confirm the basic *idea* of the syntax, I put together a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-todos-multiple-mergemap-deborahk The important thing is to ensure that what comes out of each piped operation is the desired input into the next one. Not sure this will help?